# displaying db2 error codes in SquirrelSQL

Tags: db2, squirrel-sql

When you run a query in db2 commandline tool you get explanations like:

```
db2 => select * from sysibm.systables  where owner = 'SAM'  and type = 'T';
SQL0206N  "OWNER" is not valid in the context where it is used.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

However, when ran in SQL tab in SquirrelSQL you get only:

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=OWNER, DRIVER=4.13.127
SQLState:  42703
ErrorCode: -206
```

Does anybody know of a way of making SquirrelSQL display explanation for the error code like db2 cmd line?

OS: Win 7 x64, db2 10.1

Comment: What OS is your database hosted on?  It appears that this is available for z/OS and OS/390.  Unfortunately, my databases are on linux and I'm guessing that's why I can't get it to work.  Search for retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/rjvdsprp.htm for details.

Comment: Nope, it's win7 x64. Java for Squirrel is 1.6, IBM edition, 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in DB2 plugin, I have managed to fix it and posted solution at http://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1073/